# Firefox Anchor Outline Issue

Tags: html, css, anchor, outline

The following snippet is causing me a QA headache.

```
<div id="links-container">
  <ul>
    <li class="resource-link li-sep"><a href="http://www.somesite.com/members/category/?catID=8" target="_blank"><em>Enjoy family-friendly</em>ACTIVITIES AND ATTRACTIONS <span>&raquo;</span></a></li>
    <li>...etc...</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I tried this in CSS, but nothing is working;

```
#links-container ul li a { color:#C28234; }
#links-container ul li a span { font-size:140%; line-height:1em; }
#links-container ul li a em { display:block; font-family:Georgia; font-weight:normal; margin-bottom:-6px; }
#links-container ul li a:focus em, #links-container ul li a:active em { outline:none; }
#links-container ul li a:hover { color:#75450A; }
```

What's happening is that in Firefox, when you tab through the links, it's creating outlines around both sets of text which have close proximity to each other and are causing overlapping outlines.

Our project mgrs wish to keep the outlines to promote accessibility.

If you view it in Chrome, it will wrap the entire contents of the anchor in an outline. And we consider this to be perfect. My question is, can something be done that can replicate this in Firefox. Or at the very least, clean it up so that the outline doesn't look like dung when Firefox individually outlines each text item in the same link.

Anyone else ever have to deal with this? If so, how'd you get past it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. It's a partial solution, but can work in your case. If you you have problem with menu items only you can apply "display: inline-block;" to links in here, to make it have a common outline.

Example: [jsfiddle.net/zDbsQ/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/zDbsQ/2/)

EDIT: Fixed link to example, original was wrong.

Comment: Thanks Alexey! The links in reference are not menu items, but rather just a list of links in a standard list. If you look at your Fiddle example with Chrome & tab until that link has the focus, you'll see how Chrome outlines multi-line links as a single outline. Whereas Firefox will wrap each text item separately. For the sake of not having the links look bad, I would like to achieve what Chrome is doing. Is that even possible?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot find a solution that works as Webkit browsers, maybe it exists, but I don't know about it. I fixed example (it didn't have "display: inline-block;" for some reason), it is best that I was able to do so far.

Comment: Alexey...I am still trying to see what you changed, but whatever you did is EXACTLY what I needed! Thank you soooo much! Outstanding job!

Comment: I found it. You added the display:inline-block to the anchor tag. That is awesome! Thanks a million, again!

Comment: Glad to help, inserted wrong link in initial answer, found out only today.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use:

```
#links-container ul li a *{ outline: none; }
```

This will select *all* elements within an a and disable the outline..